# Where is definied the theme location for the main menu in a WordPress template?

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, css, html

I am pretty new in WordPress (I came from Joomla) and I have the following doubt related the **Theme Location** of the main menu.

For example, using the preinstalled **Twenty Twelve** theme, if in the backend I go into: **Appearance ---> Menus ---> Manage Location** I can assign my **main-menu** only to a specific **theme location** named **Primary Menu**.

I think that this area is into the **header.php** file of the **Twenty Twelve** theme (because my main menu is shown in the page header) but I can't find it, this is the **header.php** content:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header template for our theme
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php // Loads HTML5 JavaScript file to add support for HTML5 elements in older IE versions. ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </hgroup>

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
            <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

        <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="main" class="wrapper">
```

Where is this **Primary Menu** or how is it definied in the theme?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Example of adding a new custom menu location in your theme: http://goo.gl/TbxqDy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Menu locations are defined in functions.php

You can read [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) for more information on how to define menu locations in functions.php

**Register Menus**

Firstly, in your theme's functions.php, you need to write a function to register the names of your menus. (This is how they will appear in the Appearance -> Menus admin screen.) As an example, this menu would appear in the "Theme Locations" box as "Header Menu".

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

And this would make two menu options appear, header menu and extra menu -

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
      'extra-menu' => __( 'Extra Menu' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

**Display Menus on Theme**

Once you've done that, your theme will be almost ready. The last preparation step is to tell the theme where you want the menus to show up. You do this in the relevant theme file. So, for example, we might want our header menu to be in header.php. So open up that file in the theme editor, and decide where you want to put your menu. The code to use here is wp_nav_menu which we will need once for each menu location. So, add this code -

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

All you need to ensure is that the theme_location points to the name you provided for your menu in the functions.php code above. (Note that it's the header-menu being used here rather than Header Menu without a hyphen. header-menu is the name that the code understands, Header Menu is the human-readable version that you see in the admin page.)

To complete the code, you can put your extra menu someplace else. Maybe you want a menu on one of your pages, for example, and you might even want it to be jazzed up a little with a containing DIV of a certain class -

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'extra-menu', 'container_class' => 'my_extra_menu_class' ) );
```

So you'd put the above into your Page template, and not only would the menu show up wherever you put it, it'd be styled as my_extra_menu_class so that you can work with that in CSS.

Comment: Perfect explaination !!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also hook in an extra menu from your child functions.php file without modifying any parent themes files.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_extra_nav' ); 

function add_extra_nav() {

wp_nav_menu( array( 

'theme_location' => 'extra-menu', 

'container_class' => 'nav-menu' ) );

}
```

Simply change the container class to the same as your theme uses and wrap the function in an existing class your theme uses for a primary or secondary menu so you don't need to add any CSS. You can normally find this in the header.php.

Change the wp_head hook to any other WordPress or theme specific hook.